# Changing citation template

Tags: feature-request

For every question and answer, share->cite results in a suggested BibTeX citation.  Now that people are actually [starting to cite the site](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/14547), I think we need to revise the template so it is more useful.  This would also help nudge the diversity of possible ways to cite the site into fewer likely channels.

First, the existing text "Theoretical Computer Science" is not useful, since the maximum likelihood match for that phrase is the long-established Elsevier journal of that name.  "Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange" seems a better phrase.

Second, it seems important to indicate whether the citation is to the question itself, or to a specific answer, in the text itself and not just the URL.  The title that the citation template generates is the title of the question, and I suggest something like "Response to: " as a prefix for answers, or a suffix of the form " (response)".

Finally, I would like to be able to cite specific comments, and # link to the comment.  However, SE seems to deliberately downplay comments, unlike MO, so I am not holding my breath.

Comment: Some of this is already filed as a bug: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1289/

Comment: Unfortunately, strict scholarship requires citing the site using its actual title — the string inside in the <title> tag — which is "Theoretical Computer Science".   However, "Theoretical Computer Science [Stack Exchange]" (with a space between "Stack" and "Exchange") is acceptable as disambiguation from the Evilseer journal.  The Stack Exchange site-naming policy is stupid, but we're stuck with it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe TCS Stackexchange might be better ? Not as wordy. I agree with the second point - either format would be fine with me.

Comment: Only if we can change the actual title of the site to "TCS Stack Exchange".